# No method matching arguments: java.lang.String, java.util.HashMap XMLRPC infusionsoft

Tags: php, xml-rpc, infusionsoft

I am developing code that sends an email from our website through Infusionsoft API & XMLRPC.

Here my code:

```
$email = $user_rec['email'];
    $contactID=$user_rec['client_infusionid'];      
    echo $contactID;

    $Subject = 'Your reset password request at GIC Deal Finders';

    $From = $this->GetFromAddress();

    $link = 'http://dashboard.gicdealfinders.info/resetpwd.php?email='.
            urlencode($email).'&code='.
            urlencode($this->GetResetPasswordCode($email));

    $htmlBody ='Hello '.$user_rec["name"].'<br/><br/>'.
    'There was a request to reset your password at GIC Deal Finders<br/>'.
    'Please click the link below to complete the request: <br/><a href="'.$link.'">'.$link.'</a><br/><br/>'.
     '<br/>'.
    'Regards,<br/>'.
    'Toyin Dawodu, MBA<br/>'.
    'Founder and Chief Relationship Officer';

    $clients = new xmlrpc_client("https://ze214.infusionsoft.com/api/xmlrpc");
    $clients->return_type = "phpvals";
    $clients->setSSLVerifyPeer(FALSE);
    ###Build a Key-Value Array to store a contact###
    $emailI = array(
    'contactList' => $contactID,
    'fromAddress' => $From,
    'toAddress' => $email,
    'ccAddresses' => 'admin@gicdealfinders.info',
    'bccAddresses' =>'abhilashrajr.s@gmail.com',
    'contentType' => 'HTML',
    'subject' => $Subject,
    'htmlBody' => $htmlBody,
    'textBody' => 'test');
    //$check=$myApp->sendEmail($clist,"Test@test.com","~Contact.Email~", "","","Text","Test Subject","","This is the body");

    ###Set up the call###
        $calls = new xmlrpcmsg("APIEmailService.sendEmail", array(
        php_xmlrpc_encode($this->infusion_api),         #The encrypted API key
        php_xmlrpc_encode($emailI)      #The contact array

        ));

        ###Send the call###
        $results = $clients->send($calls);
        //$conID = $results->value();
        /*###Check the returned value to see if it was successful and set it to a variable/display the results###*/
        if(!$results->faultCode()) {
            return true;
            } else {
                print $results->faultCode() . "<BR>";
                print $results->faultString() . "<BR>";
            return false;
            }
```

The captured error shows:

```
-1
No method matching arguments: java.lang.String, java.util.HashMap
```

Can anyone check my code and show me a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As the returned error says, the wrong parameters are sent to Infusionsoft API.

The list of acceptable parameters is provided in [Infusionsoft API documentation](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#email-send-an-email).

First of all, you need to add your **API key** as the **first value in $emailI** array.

Also, Infusionsoft API expects the second parameter to be a list of Contact IDs, which means the second parameter **$contactID** must be sent from php side **as an array**.

The following code shows the fixes:

```
$emailI = array(
    'yourApiKey',
    array($contactID),
    $From,
    $email,
    'admin@gicdealfinders.info',
    'abhilashrajr.s@gmail.com',
    'HTML',
    $Subject,
    $htmlBody,
    'test'
);
$calls = new xmlrpcmsg(
    "APIEmailService.sendEmail",
     array_map('php_xmlrpc_encode', $emailI)
);
```

Please also notice, that if you have more then just one or two Infusionsoft API calls in your code, it's advisable to use [API Helper Libraries](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/resources/helper-libraries/). Also you may find another wrappers for Infusionsoft API at [github.com](https://github.com/search?q=infusionsoft) if current official Helper Libraries don't work for you.

Comment: ###Set up the call###
        $calls = new xmlrpcmsg("APIEmailService.sendEmail", array(
        php_xmlrpc_encode($this->infusion_api),         #The encrypted API key
        php_xmlrpc_encode($emailI)      #The contact array

        ));

in my code php_xmlrpc_encode($this->infusion_api) store the api key

Comment: Yes, I saw it. My answer fixes your issues. Use your $this->infusion_api in place of 'yourApiKey'

Comment: i will check with it and let you know

Comment: Did you have a chance to take a look into the answer? Thanks!